# Firebase job service started with big delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-job-dispatcher, jobservice

I am testing an application that receives Firebase cloud data messages and processes them in the Firebase job service. Receiving messages in the FirebaseMessagingService occurs instantly and without problems, but the Firebase job service sometimes starts with a long delay (5-10 minutes), and sometimes it does not start at all. The dispatcher.schedule (myJob) method always gives the result SCHEDULE_RESULT_SUCCESS. This is the job scheduling functionality:

```
// For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(WatchDogService.REQUEST_ID, request.ordinal());
bundle.putString(REQUEST_PARAM, parameter);
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher =
        new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
        .setService(LongJobService.class)
        .setTag("ua.ers.LongJobService")
        .setTrigger(Trigger.NOW)
        .setReplaceCurrent(true)
        .setExtras(bundle)
        .build();
int result = dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
Log.d(TAG, "Schedule result: " + result);
```

Here is a Firebase Job Service class:

```
public class LongJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "LongJobService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LongJobService started");    
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LongJobService stopped");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tell me, please, what could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, this is just the usual behaviour

> The scheduler backend is encouraged to use the windowEnd value as a signal that the job should be run, but this is not an enforced behavior.

But for a better execution try

```
Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0)
```

instead of

```
Trigger.NOW
```

So it will look like

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
.setService(Service.class)
.setRecurring(true) // if task is periodic, else pass "false"
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
.setTag("tag")
.build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why do you propose to use .setRecurring(true)?

Comment: Well that was my implementation, but if your task is periodic, you can add this property. else just pass false.

Comment: What is the maximum value of the launch delay we can expect in your case?

Comment: What was the delay you were getting? Mine was around 10 -15 secs, after the code changes, else was 30 - 40sec

Comment: Thanks. It helps me.

Comment: Today we faced with the fact that the Job service refused to start at all until the device was rebooted. With what it can be connected?

Comment: @SolderingIronMen Can you please post the exact code, were you are initializing the Job object, need to see which all properties you are adding to it.

Comment: @Sannop, I gave the exact text of the code in question. It is called from the onMessageReceived FirebaseMessagingService method.

Comment: @SolderingIronMen I need two more information, was the result returned for the Job Schedule ( int result ) a RESULT_SUCCESS? and Can you constantly able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, I received the result RESULT_SUCCESS even in case of a problem with the launch. And I can't reproduce the problem right now.